# Show entries of cache via Spring Boots Actuator Endpoint /caches

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ehcache, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot application with Actuator and Caching running.
When I call

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/caches/myCacheName
```

I only get some basic information about target, name and cacheManager.

But I want to see all entries of this particular cache.

So is it possible to customize this endpoint that it gives me more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can customize current endpoints by extending them. This is an example using the @EndpointWebExtension annotation to extend the standard info actuator endpoint with more functionality.

example is taken from here:
[Extend actuator endpoints](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators)

Here is springs official documentation about extending endpoints:
[Spring extending endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-custom)

```
@Component
@EndpointWebExtension(endpoint = InfoEndpoint.class)
public class InfoWebEndpointExtension {

    private InfoEndpoint delegate;

    // standard constructor

    @ReadOperation
    public WebEndpointResponse<Map> info() {
        Map<String, Object> info = this.delegate.info();
        Integer status = getStatus(info);
        return new WebEndpointResponse<>(info, status);
    }

    private Integer getStatus(Map<String, Object> info) {
        // return 5xx if this is a snapshot
        return 200;
    }
}
```